# Why does the ground appear to be connected to the hot in a 240v single-phase circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I don't know much about 240 V single phase power so please bear with me! I am confused about the wiring.  Here is the situation.

In my outlet there are 3 wires, black, red and blue.  I used my Fluke multimeter to check the voltages in between these lines.  To my understanding, I should have L1 and L2 which are two signals 180 degrees apart, and a neutral.

I checked around with the multi meter until I found a voltage of 240 V and figured these were the L1 and L2 lines (red and black) and the third one (blue) must be the neutral, since the voltage between the third one and any of the other 2 was only 120.

So using just these two lines, I wired up my device (which is a DIY single phase to 3 phase converter for my milling machine) and it works just fine.  But then I realized that the machine isn't grounded.  For 120 V service, I am used to having a ground wire that I can hook up to the chassis for safety.  So I go into the distribution box that the outlet is connected to and I see bare wire, which I presume is ground.  So just to be sure, I shut off all of the power and did a continuity check between this bare wire and each wire in the outlet and I got continuity with the red wire!  I don't understand this at all since the red and black were my L1 and L2 lines!

Can anyone explain why this is the case?  I am pretty sure I CANNOT use the neutral line as a chassis ground and I want this machine to be grounded.  Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:  In regards to wire color code.  I am located in central PA.

Comment: Blue is a neutral on equipment mfg for CE listing (overseas) Being a licensed electrician here in the U.S. it was difficult to get used to equipment that was built in other countries that used Blue as the neutral. It is possible to see a low impedance to ground / neutral through devices like transformers and lamps that look to be a short to DC (meters use DC to measure resistance).

Comment: What kind of outlet and plug are you using? If you don't know, post a picture. This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector

Comment: @EdBeal, it sounds like the OP is saying there is a blue wire in the outlet. Have you seen blue wire used for neutral in a residential installation in the US? Would that satisfy code? To the OP, is the blue wire actually in the outlet in the wall?

Comment: Was there also continuity between the bare wire and the blue wire in the outlet?

Comment: I was thinking the outlet on a phase converter. the neutral should be white or identified, marked white if a cable assembly was used to wire the outlet that had non standard colors, I have seen that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Red, black and blue are **the classic colors** for 3-phase power (other than wild-leg).  The color combination does not specify voltage; that's what voltmeters are for.

An important factor is the lack of neutral.  In the U.S. neutrals must be white or gray.  It is illegal to "tape" or "paint" another wire color to be neutral, unless the wire is 4 AWG or larger.  Measure the voltage between each wire and ground/earth.  You should get a significant voltage if the wires are not wrong-colored.

How well do you *really* know the wiring here?  Are you sure you don't already have 3-phase or maybe someone beat you to it and installed a phase converter somewhere?  Maybe that has since been removed?   No kidding, I have a 240V 3-phase converter at a 120-240 service panel, that panel's transformer is *fed* from 3-phase service which is literally 20 feet away from it.  The things people do!

Now, the red wire being grounded is *just wrong*.  However this could occur if the grounding system is not proper, or if the neutral-ground bond has failed.  (And I have one of those in a panel *right now*.) All it takes is one ground-fault to "lift the ground" to hot potential (or more accurately, lower the hot to grounding potential, lifting the neutral away from ground.)

Comment: Maybe the wire is really green, but has faded or discolored in such a way that the OP thinks it is blue. This would explain everything, including the voltages reported by the OP. The OP said red-to-black is 240 and both red and black are 120 to the "blue" wire.

Comment: He also says red and ground are the same potential.  That's super wrong.

Comment: Nope. Not at the same potential. He said they showed continuity when the main power was disconnected. That makes sense. If the DC resistance of the load is small enough, it will be recognized as continuity by the Ohm-meter.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys!So I went back, turned on the power, and measured the voltage between each wire and the ground. For two of the wires, I got 120 volts each (red and black) and the blue one I got pretty much zero(so this is prob neutral,which makes sense with the way themachine is wired).
When I initially did the continuity check, I got like 4 ohms.Is it possible that it simply is a low impedance path to ground as you suggestedBecause there WAS a potential difference between the ground and the red and black wires when the power was on....  Can I use this ground to ground my chasis?

Comment: @user41178 not at 4 ohms you can't.  Worst case, run a proper ground, the rules now give you a lot of latitude to do that.  Are you in metal conduit? That is the ground.  What's happening at the other end of that cable run?   Mkeith thinks the blue wire is a ground wire that's faded, green wires will also look blue under sodium lights.   Try lighting it up with a cell phone and see if it still looks blue.

Comment: Yes I am in metal conduit.  The conduit goes into the outlet housing  (which is metal) so I think I will just connect the ground to that.  

Do you mean what is happening at the breaker? I will have to go look tomorrow.  The shop is lit up with white fluorescent light that is fairly bright so I am sure the wire is indeed blue.  

How the heck did I get a 4 ohm connection to ground?  Thanks for all of the help and comments.  This has been very helpful!

Comment: Condui as ground is very common.  Freaked me out when I first got into an entire factory and couldn't find a ground wire anywhere.  In conduit they can choose ANY wire color they want, so if they meant white or gray they woulda used it.  4 ohms sounds like the resistance through an incandescent lamp or motor, i.e. This again suggests you are looking at a hot phase.  I would look very carefully at your panel.  Is this in a residence?

Comment: @harper 4 ohms to ground is not bad, most digital meters do not properly zero, I have measured dozens of driven grounding electrodes and rarely have values less than 15 ohms with 2 rods and many times as high as 100. I have a 3 point tester and also use my plants clamp tester to verify. When setting a new service vault for both homes and at the plant. the only consistent very low impedance connections I have found is from Ufer grounds (concrete encased).

Comment: @EdBeal unless I misunderstand, he's referring to *equipment grounding conductor* within the service, and the grounding electrocde doesn't enter into it.  He's saying the blue wire is 4 ohms from the ground *wire*, (which happens to be conduit).  If blue was neutral and properly bonded to EGC, that number should be smaller than 4 ohms.  Honestly all this probing is no substitue for following the wire back to the panel.

Comment: I bet it used to be ungrounded three-phase and someone re-wired it using the blue wire for either GND or neutral. Agree the OP should just follow it back. It would also be good to know what type of plug it is, so we know whether the blue wire is SUPPOSED to be ground or neutral. Is it NEMA 6-30 (a grounded type)? Or NEMA 10-30 (ungrounded type) or something else?